# How to prevent Resharper from deleting my comments when removing curly braces around single statements?

Tags: c#, resharper

R# helps me with removing curly braces around single-statement blocks and I like that. However I usually leave comments there and they're getting deleted every time the the curly braces are removed, despite that it's legal in C# to keep these comments exactly where they are without the curly braces.

The following sample:

```
if (true)
{
    // comment.
    Call();
}
```

Is being reformatted into this:

```
if (true)
    Call();
```

Instead of this:

```
if (true)
    // comment.
    Call();
```

And I need my comments to be exactly there before each call, not before the if/else statements. How do I prevent R# from deleting my comments when removing those braces?

Comment: Clean code requires no comments : / Wouldn't summary documentation of the method suffice?

Comment: Ugh, single statement blocks - I hate them. But, each to their own I suppose! And adding a comment in that format too just makes the code slightly less readable to me. Anyway, I'm not sure you can change this behaviour.

Comment: Haha :D, I like single statement blocks! And I also document my entire project with XML too. I still leave a lot of comments because I want people to understand my code in GitHub as they read the source code.

Comment: And what version of Resharper? In my version it works fine (does not remove comments).

Comment: @VladimirPavelka, I don't agree that your statement. Comments should not describe what code does (the usual problem with them). Comments are there to describe *why* it is doing what it does, where the reason is not immediately apparent or where subtleties could result in bad refactoring decisions.

Comment: I use the Rider IDE and it is version 2017.3.1, what version is your R#?

Comment: I have version 2017.3.3 (I use with Visual Studio, not sure if that matters).

Comment: I've updated my version to 2018.1.1, a whole new R# IDE, yet the same problem persists. Could there be a setting for that?

Comment: Setting like "Don't delete my comments while refactoring"? I doubt that :)

Comment: R# has had lots of bugs over the years where comments are deleted / removed during R# operations. [Here's yours, RSRP-468292](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468292).

Comment: @AakashM Thanks! I've up-voted that with the hope it'll be included in next versions of R#. At the moment I just enforce brackets because I had no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue was fixed in Rider 2019.1**, and Resharper on Rider 2019.1 no longer deletes comments within optional braces if they're being removed automatically while applying the formatting style or performing code cleanup.